# which favicon gets loaded in the browser?

Tags: favicon, png

currently i am experimenting with 2 favicons and including them in 3 different ways in my markup, however i am not sure which one gets loaded in the browser. firebug's network tab doesn't tell me which one it downloaded.

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.png">
```

where favicon.png is 144x144px and favicon.ico is 16x16px.

idealy i want all browsers to use the png instead of ico whenever they support it, and just fallback to ico for ie. i am not sure how to verify if the code is already doing this or not.

Comment: try 3 different pictures

Comment: sure i can use a different image for apple-touch-icon, but then my question still stands, which one will get loaded? i don't want a browser to load and use favicon.ico when favicon.png and apple-touch-icon are available, for example... i want to know what order should i put them in, if i just want browsers to load the highest resolution they support for.

Comment: Again, you can test this by using 3 different images. One blue, one green one red. Test them, play with the order and you will find out.

Answer (score 1):

You should also change the order from lowest resolution, to highest.  Since the browsers will use the last instance that they can use.

Your:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.png">
```

Should be:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.png">
```

So any browser that is looking for `rel="icon"` and can use the .png, will.

Comment: That's not accurate. Some browsers behave exactly the opposite way, regarding favicons

Answer (score 0):

According to a [Wikipedia article on how to use Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use), the recommended way to use a favicon is with the code `<link rel="shortcut icon"
 href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />` because (of course) Internet Explorer doesn't understand PNG, and GIF as a icon or the `type` attribute. You should also place `favicon.ico` in the root directory of your website so it is `http://example.com/favicon.ico`.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the favicon manually for IE:

```
/*!
 * Dynamically changing favicons with JavaScript
 * Works in all A-grade browsers except Safari and Internet Explorer
 * Demo: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/dynamic-favicons
 */

// HTML5™, baby! http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/document-head
document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

function changeFavicon(src) {
 var link = document.createElement('link'),
     oldLink = document.getElementById('dynamic-favicon');
 link.id = 'dynamic-favicon';
 link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
 link.href = src;
 if (oldLink) {
  document.head.removeChild(oldLink);
 }
 document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: You state "You can change the favicon manually for IE:", yet the comment at the top of your code states "except... Internet Explorer"?!